# How do i know if a min/max point in a 2 variable function is an absolute min/max

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I know that in order to find min/max in 2 variable function we calculate:

$$
f_{xx},f_{xy},f_{yy}
$$

Then doing:

$$
f_{xx}f{yy}-f_{xy}^2
$$

And conclude if it a min/max point or not.

But assume i find a min/max point, how do i know if its an *absolute* min/max point?

Comment: Find all extrema, then whichever the largest/smallest ones are are the absolute extrema.

Answer (score 1):

Calculate the critical points using $D=f_{xx}f_{yy}-{f_{xy}}^2$ then compare the critical points as you would in Calculus 1.  If you find three relative minimum points plug in the three points into $f(x,y)$ and see which point is the smallest: thats the absolute minimum.

Comment: What about the boundries of the domain? shouldnt i check them like a function in 1 variable?

Comment: Yes you should. You can often parametrize the boundary as a single variable function and then look for extrema using techniques from calc 1.

Answer (score 0):

A function $f(x,y)$ has a relative minimum at the point $(a,b)$ if $f(x,y)≥f(a,b)$ for all points $(x,y)$ in some region around $(a,b)$.

A function $f(x,y)$ has a relative minimum at the point $(a,b)$ if $f(x,y)≤f(a,b)$ for all points $(x,y)$ in some region around $(a,b)$.

Note that this definition does not say that a relative minimum is the smallest value that the function will ever take. It only says that in some region around the point $(a,b)$ the function will always be larger than $f(a,b)$. Outside of that region it is completely possible for the function to be smaller. Likewise, a relative maximum only says that around $(a,b)$the function will always be smaller than $f(a,b)$. Again, outside of the region it is completely possible that the function will be larger.

Suppose that $(a,b)$ is a critical point of $f(x,y)$ and that the second order partial derivatives are continuous in some region that contains $(a,b)$. Next define,

$D=D(a,b)=f_{xx}(a,b)f_{yy}(a,b)−[f_{xy}(a,b)]^2$

We then have the following classifications of the critical point.

If $D>0$ and $f_{xx}(a,b)>0$ then there is a relative minimum at $(a,b)$.

If $D>0$ and $f_{xx}(a,b)<0$ then there is a relative maximum at $(a,b)$.

If $D<0$ then the point $(a,b)$ is a saddle point.

If $D=0$ then the point $(a,b)$ may be a relative minimum, relative maximum or a saddle point. Other techniques would need to be used to classify the critical point.

You can find more details [here](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/RelativeExtrema.aspx).